# Click and hold button in R shiny?

Tags: r, button, shiny

I would like to be able to change the value of a parameter by clicking on a R shiny button. So I need to buttons, one for increasing and one for decreasing the value.

I would like to keep the de-/increase  of the value with a certain speed while holding the button.

By releasing the click of the button the action should stop.

So far I have not found this option for the `actionButtons` in R shiny. Is there another type of button which gives this opportunity?

Comment: is this helping you http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html

Comment: Yes a bit, but the Loop Animation with the play button described there is not the one I was looking for. I was looking for a button which reacts by hold the click of the button.